# Error while installing Azure .NET SDK for visual studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am getting the following error message while installing the .NET SDK for azure from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/
[image]

How to fix this issue? I have the latest SSDT installed but still having the issue.

[image]

Comment: did you try enabling the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015, like the message suggests? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools are installed by default, unless you selected a custom installation option for Visual Studio and chose not to install them.  If they are not installed, then you need to modify your Visual Studio installation and add them.

Comment: Yes i have installed the SQL server data tools. My SSIS works too.

Comment: well that doesn't make sense; the Azure installer clearly thinks that you don't have LocalDb installed.

Comment: @Claies  have added the screen shot of the version of SSDT installed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that VS2015 installs a core set of SQL Server functionality by default even if the "SQL Server Data Tools" checkbox is not selected during installation. This results in "SQL Server Data Tools" showing as installed even though some components like LocalDB are left out.

In your case you need to modify VS2015 in Add/Remove Programes. This will let you go in and enable this checkbox, which will install LocalDB.